# How can I trim this Swift string?

Tags: ios, string, swift, trim

I have a bunch of addresses as strings that are in the following example format:

**8 Smith st, Sydney, New South Wales, Australia**

However, I'd like to trim them down to the following format:

**8 Smith st, Sydney**

How can I acheive this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## here you can trim White space using this

```
var myString = "    Let's trim the whitespace    "
var newString = myString.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
//Returns "Let's trim the whitespace"
```

in your Case, first you have to convert it in Array and then convert it as a string as given in below Example

```
var myString = "Berlin, Paris, New York, San Francisco"
var myArray = myString.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
//Returns an array with the following values:  ["Berlin", " Paris", " New York", " San Francisco"]
```

[For More you can learn From here](http://www.learnswiftonline.com/reference-guides/string-reference-guide-for-swift/)

Answer (score 1):

in your Case, first you have to convert it in Array and then convert it as a string as given in below Example

```
var myString = "8 Smith st, Sydney, New South Wales, Australia"
var myArray = myString.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
//Returns an array with the following values:  ["8 Smith st", " Sydney", " New South Wales", " Australia"]

if myArray.count > 1
{
    println(myArray[0]) //8 Smith st
    println(myArray[1]) //Sydney
}
```

Comment: println(myArray[0]+","+myArray[1])

Answer (score 0):

**Truncate string/text to Specific Length**

> If you have entered block of sentence/text and you want to save only specified length out of it text. Add the following extension to Class

```
extension String {

   func trunc(_ length: Int) -> String {
    if self.characters.count > length {
        return self.substring(to: self.characters.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: length))
    } else {
        return self
    }
  }
}
```

> Use

```
var str = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."
//str is length 74
print(str)
//O/P:  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

str = str.trunc(40)
print(str)
//O/P: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
```